# how to get x-axis line and value of the google bar chart to the top of the chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Im using google chart for my application. I need a chart like

**Expected**
[image]

and i used this code to get the expected chart.

```
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
            function drawVisualization() {
                // Create and populate the data table.
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['numbers', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria'],
                    [2003, 1336060, 400361],
                    [2004, 1538156, 366849],
                    [2005, 1576579, 440514],
                    [2006, 1600652, 434552],
                    [2007, 1968113, 393032],
                    [2008, 1901067, 517206]
                ]);
                var hAxisTick = [{v: '2003', f: "3-4"}, {v: '2004', f: "5-9"}, {v: '2005', f: "9-13"}, {v: '2006', f: "13-14"}, {v: '2007', f: "14-24"}, {v: '2008', f: "24-84"}];
                var vAxisTick = [0, 1968113];
                // Create and draw the visualization.
                new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
                        draw(data,
                                {width: 600, height: 250,
                                    colors: ['706C6B', 'D6D3D3'],
                                    legend: {position: 'none'},
                                    vAxis: {ticks: hAxisTick, gridlines: {color: 'FFFFFF'}},
                                    hAxis: {gridlines: {color: 'FFFFFF'}, ticks: vAxisTick, baselineColor: '#FFFFFF'},
                                    enableInteractivity: false}
                        );
            }
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

but,

**Actual**

[image]

how to get the x-axis line to the top and also i need to show the tick mark for the given points.

Comment: Very similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775006/google-charts-vaxis-to-the-right/15778194#15778194).

Comment: i could not find the solution from the linechart example from that line. If u dont mine please give any idea or code to get the solution in BarChart.

Comment: I tried, but I can't get the second axis to appear with your code. It may be related to the new version, and I don't have time to troubleshoot it...

Comment: see reference for [top-x-charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#top-x-charts)...