# Google Charts API - chart with two yAxis - like the one from Google Sheets

Tags: charts

I did quite a big research and I can not believe that **with the current version of the Google Charts API I cannot do a chart like the one in Google Sheets** - https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2451203?hl=en with **2 yAxis with independant** values and one common xAxis.

*Update: So far I managed to do a bar & line chart. I need exactly the same thing but now the vAxis on left has values from 1 to 5. I need **additional vAxis on right that has values from 0 to 2** (currently, there is an additional xAxis for "STD", but it's values are not 0 to 2, but 1 to 5)

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Month', 'Cups', 'STD'],
        ['2.2',  4.1,      1.5],
        ['2.3',  2.1,      1],
        ['2.4',  3,      1.4],
        ['2.6',  2,      1.2],
        ['2.7',  2,      1.3],
        ['2.1',  1.1,      1.7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
      hAxis: {title: "Month"},
      vAxis: {
        title: "Cups",
        gridlines: {
            count: 5
        },
        baseline: 1,
        format: "#"
    },
      seriesType: "bars",
      series: {1: {type: "line"}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. You have answer here: [google charts vAxis to the right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775006/google-charts-vaxis-to-the-right/15778194#15778194). There are also some other similar questions with answers.

Comment: No, I don't need a chart with vAxis to the right. I need a combo chart with 2 vAxis - each with different vAxis values. Please see this example: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2451203?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Month', 'AVRG', 'STD'],
        ['Item 1',  4.1,      1.5],
        ['Item 2',  2.1,      1.1],
        ['Item 3',  3,      0.7],
        ['Item 4',  2,      1.5],
        ['Item 5',  2,      1.7],
        ['Item 6',  1.1,      0.3]
    ]);

    var options = {
    title : 'Title',
    hAxis: {title: "Month"},
    vAxes:[
        {
            title: "AVRG",
            gridlines: {
                count: 5
            },
            baseline: 1,
            format: "#"
        },
        {
            title: "STD",
            gridlines: {
                count: 2
            },
            baseline: 0,
            format: "#"
        }
    ],
    series:[
        {targetAxisIndex:0},
        {targetAxisIndex:1, type: "line"}
    ],
    seriesType: "bars"
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```