# How to set vAxis justification in Google Charts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Apps Script to build an EmbeddedChart in a Google sheet.  By default the vertical axis labels are right-aligned, but I need them to be left-aligned.  (Below is a little screen-shot/sketch that shows what I'm trying to do).  I see a number of options for formatting the vAxis text using the setOption() method of the EmbeddedChartBuilder object, as in the code sample below.  But I can't find any simple solution for aligning the labels.

The documentation I've consulted is the list titled *Configuration options* located at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

This seems to be an exhaustive list, so maybe what I want to do isn't possible.

The only solution that cames to mind was to pad the end of each label string with whitespace to create the appearance of being left-aligned.  But this doesn't work since it turns out that whitespace is automatically truncated when the chart is built.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
      .asBarChart()
      .addRange(range)
      .setPosition(1, 1, 1, 1)
      .setTitle('Sales')
      .setXAxisTitle('Month')
      .setOption('vAxis.textStyle.fontSize','12')
      .build();
    sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [**`vAxis.textPosition`**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#Configuration_Options), this will help you position your vAxis text.

> Position of the vertical axis text, relative to the chart area. Supported values: `'out', 'in', 'none'`.

Sample Code:

```
.setOption('vAxis.textPosition','out')
```

Also you might want to check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15778194/5995040).

Hope this helps!